# sorting an arraylist by the value of an object method

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I want to sort out my `Arraylist<Book> b` on the values returned by the method `numPoints()` in class `Book`. `show()` is a method of class `Book`, that prints out the code.
Everything else works okay, just the method `sort()` is the problem i think.

```
public class som {
private static ArrayList<Book> b;

public static void main(String[] args) {


b = new ArrayList<Book>();
...
}
...

public static void sort() {
    Book mon = null;
    int indMax = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<b.size()-1; i++){
        mon = b.get(i);
        indMax = i;
        for(int j=i+1; j<b.size(); j++){
            if(b.get(j).numPoints() > mon.numPoints()){
                mon = b.get(j);
            }
        }
        if(indMax != i){
            b.set(indMax, b.get(i));
            b.set(i, mon);
        }

    }
    for(int s=0; s<b.size(); s++) {
        b.get(j).show();
    }
}

class Book {
...
     public double numPoints() {
      ...
     }
     public void show() {
     ...
     }


...
}
```

i also tried the following code, but neither of them work properly.

```
public static void sort() {
    ArrayList<Book> o = new ArrayList<Book>();
    double vMax=0;
    int iMax=0;
    while(b.size()!=0) {
        for(int i = 0; i<b.size(); i++)  {
            if(vMax<b.get(i).numPoints()) {
                vMax=b.get(i).numPoints();
                iMax=i;
            }
        }
        o.add(b.get(iMax));
        b.remove(iMax);
    }

    for(int j=0; j<o.size(); j++) {
        o.get(j).show();
    }
```

The first one just doesn't work properly, but in the second one terminal prints out :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2

can somebody please help me figure out what is wrong?

Comment: `class Object ` is going to be extremely confusing.  You should name the class something besides `Object`.  As to sorting the list, please read the [Oracle Java tutorial on "Object Ordering"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)

Comment: okay, thanks. I actually named it differently in my original code, but because it wasn't in english, i renamed it for this question so it wouldn't be confusing. guess i chose the wrong name to do this haha

Comment: i edited the question, so instead of Object there is a class Book

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are interested in having working code, not implementing sorting from scratch.

Just use already implemented sort method of list:

```
ArrayList<Book> list;
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Book::numPoints));
```

The `sort` method accepts `Comparator`.`Comparator`'s job is to compare objects.

Function `Comparator.comparing` creates comparators. It accepts one parameter that is a `Function`. `Function`'s job is to provide substitute for an object that would be compared. so the substitute can be compared instead.

Because you want to compare `Book`s by what `Book.numPoints` method returns, we need to create a function that for each `Book` returns result of `Book.numPoints` method. Because `Function` is a functional interface we can use method reference (`Book::numPoints`) to provide the function.

Then you can call `show` on all of them:

```
list.forEach(Book::show)
```

Not only it is simple, but it is easy to modify.

Answer (score 1):

For java >= java 8

```
b.sort((b1,b2)-> b1.numPoints()-b2.numPoints());
```

For java < java 8

```
Collections.sort(b,new Comparator<Book>{
            @Override
            public int compare(Book b1, Book b2) {
                return b1.numPoints() - b2.numPoints();
            }
});
```